# EF - Many To Many Detect dirty inserts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, fluent

I have an entity like below

```
public class Property {
   public string PropertyID {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Property> IncludedProperties {get;set;}
   public string value {get;set;}
}
```

That is, a property has a value, it can also include other properties. I want to restrict the user such that only existing properties can be included in IncludedProperties list. Out of the box in EF the behaviour I see is if I add a new Property,which is not yet created, to IncludedProperties, EF creates a new row for that new Property and adds to the collection. However I want to stop the user from doing it. How do I go about it?  Inserting the new Property first then including it in other property is fine and is the correct way.

**EDIT**:
A Simple test case

```
        var property1=new Propert {PropertyID = "P1"};
        uow.PropertyRepository.Insert(property1);
        uow.Save();
        var property2= new Propert  {PropertyID = "P2"};
        uow.PropertyRepository.Insert(property2);
        property2.IncludedProperties.Add(property1);
        property2.IncludedProperties.Add(new Propert {PropertyID = "P3"});
        uow.Save();
```

In this testcase, I want Save to raise exception as P3 is not a role yet.

Comment: Please show your code where you add a new property to `IncludedProperties`. And what do you mean by _I want to stop the user from doing it_. Stop doing exactly what?

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated question with a testcase for clarity.

Comment: Well, a user doesn't type code. _You_ decide not to `Insert` P3 for some reason. I _think_ you need a check whether the change tracker "knows" all properties before they are saved, but it's still not entirely clear to me how a user could decide to add a new property without first inserting it.